# How do I debug slow `ansible` (and `ansible-plabook`)?

Tags: ansible, devops

I'm facing a huge slow while managing a specific remote host with a specific role.

I have tracked down the source of the slowness and found that for a very specific variable (defined for that specific host and used by that specific role), `ansible` and `ansible-playbook` takes up to 30 seconds to build it while for other variables it takes few seconds only.

I have activated verbose mode and checked log file but nothing unusual except that `ansible` is completely silent (no logs are added) for a very long time for the problematic variable.

My questions:

- is there a way to debug `ansible` to get the root cause of the issue I'm facing?
- anybody can suggest an explanation of this behavior?

Here is the outcome of printing the problematic variable `iptables` and another normal variable `ifcfg`:

```
time ansible fw1 -m debug -a "msg={{iptables}}" -vvvvvv
...
real    0m25.097s
user    0m26.564s
sys 0m0.272s

time ansible fw1 -m debug -a "msg={{ifcfg}}"
...
real    0m2.584s
user    0m2.636s
sys 0m0.097s
```

Here is ansible logs for the first command:

```
2021-06-04 09:53:18,239 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | ansible 2.9.21
  config file = /path/to/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/path/to/.libs']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
2021-06-04 09:53:18,239 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | Using /path/to/ansible.cfg as config file
2021-06-04 09:53:18,239 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | Reading vault password file: /path/to/ansible_vault_passwords
.
.
.
2021-06-04 09:53:18,472 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | Decrypt of "/path/to/vault.yml" successful with secret=FileVaultSecret(filename='/path/to/ansible_vault_passwords') and vault_id=default
2021-06-04 09:53:44,250 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | fw1 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": {
        "allow": {
            "ping": true, 
            "ssl": true
        }, 
        "forward": {
            "enabled": true, 
            "http": {
                "khlass_prd_bc_to_khlass_prd_app": {
                    "enabled": false, 
                    "source": "11.5.40.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.20.0/24"
                }, 
                "khlass_prd_dmz_to_khlass_prd_app": {
                    "enabled": false, 
                    "source": "11.5.10.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.20.0/24"
                }
            }, 
            "https": {
                "khlass_prd_bc_to_khlass_prd_app": {
                    "enabled": true, 
                    "source": "11.5.40.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.20.0/24"
                }, 
                "khlass_prd_dmz_to_khlass_prd_app": {
                    "enabled": true, 
                    "source": "11.5.10.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.20.0/24"
                }
            }, 
            "mariadb": {
                "khlass_prd_app_to_khlass_prd_db": {
                    "enabled": true, 
                    "source": "11.5.20.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.30.0/24"
                }
            }, 
            "service": {
                "khlass_prd_app_to_bc_api": {
                    "enabled": true, 
                    "port": "8447", 
                    "source": "11.5.20.0/24", 
                    "target": "11.5.40.0/24"
                }
            }
        }, 
        "log": {
            "filtered": true
        }, 
        "remove_firewalld": true
    }
}
2021-06-04 09:53:44,250 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | META: ran handlers
2021-06-04 09:53:44,250 p=22258 u=yo n=ansible | META: ran handlers
```

Comment: How are those vars declared exactly ? Are they using any lookup function ? Does your inventory contain a lot of vault encrypted strings/files ? If yes, did you install `cryptography` as advised ? (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#speeding-up-ansible-vault)

Comment: All variables are either group variables, hosts variables or role defaults variable. Each variable has its own `yml` file. I was suspecting that the number of files that hold variables can be the source of the issue but printing another variable for the same host (hence requires loading the same files) is fast. The same applies for the encrypted variables. They can not be the source of the issue as they are decrypted very fast for the other variable. Besides, the logs show that encrypted variables are all loaded in less a second.

Comment: This still does not tell if this var contains a lookup, filter, test, specific Jinja expression.... in its declaration

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. A lot of sens as these elements are variable-specific. I don't use `lookup` function, not yet. I will check the used filters, tests and J2 expressions and share the outcome here.

Comment: For this variable, no filter is used. Only simple J2 expression to evaluate a variable or an inline `if/else` expression with some times the `defined` test. A question please @Zeitounator: is there a way to profile `ansible` command?

Comment: You already did profile it. Please don't describe what your code looks like: edit your question and show it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zeitounator, you questions helped a lot and my issue is solved now. I have three variables A, B and C (well they are not simple variables but rather dictionaries with several levels) : B references A and C references B. I have managed to reference A directly in C without using B and now the evaluation of C has a normal speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **`@Zeitounator`**, I have solved the issue.

The `iptables` variable is a dictionary with several levels and I have two more variables `nets` and `ifcfg` that are also dictionaries with several levels.

Many values of `iptables` are set with values from `ifcfg` that are set using values from `nets`.

I have managed to set values in `iptables` using values from `nets` directly and now the evaluation of `iptables` is as fast as the other variables.